# change the TAB character length in a XUL textbox element

Tags: xul

Is it possible to change the length of the TAB (\t) character (currently 8 characters) displayed in a XUL <textbox> element ?

Note that I want to avoid replacing TABs with spaces.

Comment: Don't think it's possible without replacing tabs with spaces, interesting discussion of the general CSS case here: http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/comp-info-authoring-css/365851-change-tab-width-using-css.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS 2.1 spec specifies tabs be rendered as the width of 8 spaces. ([Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model)) I don't see any mozilla specific CSS to override that value.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert of XUL, but I would say no. From the docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox

I see no property to set this, nor any setting in the firefox about:config.

Comment: Also I would suspect that it's system specific.

Answer (score 1):

Dug through the source for this. It appears that this is hard coded to 8 characters within the layout engine itself.

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla1.9.2/source/layout/generic/nsTextFrameThebes.cpp#2483

Looks like tab replacement is the only option if tab-stop rendering is necessary :(

Answer (score 1):

as we speak, it is possible with [-moz-tab-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-tab-size), and in CSS3, it will (most likely) be possible with [tab-size](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/#tab-size).